# Urgent - Need to increase total supply of deployed contract - ERC20

Tags: erc-20

I would like to clean this code up and NEED to increase the total supply by 15,300,000 to total 17,000,000.  There was a 0 missing when I originally deployed this to the main net but I've already submitted it many places and about to do an airdrop.  Can anyone help?  Contract code below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Token {

/// @return total amount of tokens
function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply) {}

/// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
/// @return The balance
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {}

/// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
/// @param _to The address of the recipient
/// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
/// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

/// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
/// @param _from The address of the sender
/// @param _to The address of the recipient
/// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
/// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

/// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_addr` to spend `_value` tokens
/// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
/// @param _value The amount of wei to be approved for transfer
/// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

/// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
/// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
/// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {}

event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}



contract StandardToken is Token {

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
    //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
    //Replace the if with this one instead.
    //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
    //if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
    if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
  return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}

mapping (address => uint256) balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
uint256 public totalSupply;
}


//name this contract whatever you'd like
contract Verdot is StandardToken {

function () {
    //if ether is sent to this address, send it back.
    throw;
}

/* Public variables of the token */

/*
NOTE:
The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
*/
string public name;                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
uint8 public decimals;                //How many decimals to show. ie. There could 1000 base units with 3 decimals. Meaning 0.980 SBX = 980 base units. It's like comparing 1 wei to 1 ether.
string public symbol;                 //An identifier: eg SBX
string public version = 'H1.0';       //human 0.1 standard. Just an arbitrary versioning scheme.

//
// CHANGE THESE VALUES FOR YOUR TOKEN
//

//make sure this function name matches the contract name above. So if you're token is called TutorialToken, make sure the //contract name above is also TutorialToken instead of ERC20Token

function Verdot(
    ) {
    balances[msg.sender] =17000000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens (100000 for example)
    totalSupply =17000000;                        // Update total supply (100000 for example)
    name = "Verdot";                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    decimals = 0;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    symbol = "VRD";                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
}

/* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

    //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
    //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
    //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
    if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; }
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: You haven't added any function to increase the total supply after deployment of the contract. So there is no way to increase the total supply. You have to deploy a new contract if you want to increase the total supply

Comment: Oh well that's not good at all.  I've already created a new contract on the test net because I figured as much but wanted to ask the experts here.  The total balance I have in my wallet is 17,000,000 but total supply is only 1,700,000.

Comment: can you verify the smart contract code in etherscan and share the contract address?

Comment: Yes, it's been verified - the contract address is 0x85bae89dcf0598fb835e2e015b72c3c67a65896a - it would be so wonderful to not have to create another contract for so many reasons.  Thank you so much for looking at this.

Comment: While deploying the contract you gave total supply as 1,700,000 instead of 17,000,000. The etherscan will fetch the total supply using the public variable totalSupply. So there is no way of modifying it. You have to deploy the new contract with the exact values.

Comment: By the way, for the future reference - for this exact reason you want to write your long numbers as `17 * 10 ** 6` instead of `17000000` - this way it's much harder to make a mistake as you see the number of zeroes (6) right away without having to count them.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to redeploy. I would also change other things in this contract because looks a little bit hardcoded + uses the constructor in a way it is deprecated. For example, replace your "Verdot" function / constructor with this:

```
constructor(
    ) public{
    totalSupply =170000000;                 // set total supply               
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;               // Give the creator all initial tokens (100000 for example)
    totalSupply =17000000;                              
    name = "Verdot";                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    decimals = 0;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    symbol = "VRD";                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }
```

To avoid future problems use my strategy. First write your number with commas such as:

> 17,000,000

Then just remove the commas

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter the source code of a contract once it's deployed therefore it's not possible to change the total supply in your scenario.